# Javascript animations

Tags: javascript, animation

How would someone go about writing javascript animations that are very customized, similar to the ones here: https://fiber.google.com/about/

Comment: That's a very very very very vague question... personally I would use VIM.

Comment: How would I got about answering your question, answers similar to the ones here: http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/10-impressive-javascript-animation-frameworks/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that particular site (the rabbit animation at least) uses `Swiffy.js`. Swiffy converts ActionScript/Flash to HTML/JSON and then renders it using mainly SVG, effectively allowing developers to write flash animations and not have to worry about clients having the flash plugin. Which is good, since as of 2011 flash seems to be taking a bit of a decline. This is due mostly to the fact that Apple is focusing on HTML5 rather than flash, so iDevices will never be able to view flash. Because of that, web developers are hesitant to embed flash, as they'll have to provide a second option for mobile viewers.

So, in this case, your answer is "Learn Flash, then learn Swiffy, then realize that the whole thing could have been done more easily with another JS library".

Answer (score 3):

They're using SVG for those animations, in which case I would recommend familiarizing yourself with [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/).

Comment: technically they're using ActionScript converted to JSon Via swiffy and *then* it's rendered using (mostly) SVG. So in this case, if he wants to make animations exactly like this, he'd be better off learning flash. Though I can't in good conscience recommend anyone learning flash, since it's essentially dead at this point.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt Flash is not dead for _all_ potential uses, we have just passed its days as a website killer. Making games in ActionScript, animated shorts, and other such applications is still a thriving practice.

Comment: @TheZ Yeah, you're right. Very good point. I really just meant in the area of HTML-embedded flash since flash player is becoming less and less existant, but I should have clarified. Also I guess the existence of Adobe Air means that it'll never *totally* die

Answer (score 0):

also you can download [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) in order to see the pages code and explore it to see if you can figure out how they created it.

Here is a good place to get started i think [10 javascript animation frameworks](http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/10-impressive-javascript-animation-frameworks/)

also you could make it in flash and upload the animation